# Respond to employers on Careers 2.0 via email

Tags: feature-request, jobs, email

I think it would be a valuable feature to be able to reply to emails from employers on Careers 2.0 via email.  I have Careers send me an email notification with the message contents every time I get a message on Careers 2.0, but it would be significantly easier for me to just click "reply" than have to go to the site, log in, and respond.

Would it be possible to replying by email as a feature?

Comment: Yeah, but then Careeres can't track how well they are doing for the people who pay them (employers...).

Comment: Sure they can.  The reply-to can be a Stackoverflow system that just adds to the conversation--a unique id like `careers-conversation-ajfje9293wejf8370191@careers.stackoverflow.com` or something, and it simply replies to the conversation as you would from the browser, except via email instead.